# How to fill empty spots in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking to fill empty spots such as `[,,]` in an array with the value of `null`. If there are 2 `,` I need 3 elements

I also want this to work in the case that an array looks like this: `[value,,]` or `[, value,]` or `[,,value]`

```
if (Object.values(row).length !== row.length) {
  let newRow: any[];
  newRow = row.map(el => {
    if (el) {
      return el;
    } else {
      return 'null';
    }
  });
  console.log('newRow:: ', newRow);
  return newRow;
}
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your source array

Comment: "*If there are 2 , I need 3 elements*" that is not possible `[,,]` defines an array with *two* empty slots. There is no relation between the array you get and the code that produced it. `[,,]` is *the same as* `Array(2)` or `new Array(2)`. Therefore, if you have an array, it's not possible to know whether the 2 empty slots should *actually* be 3 based on the creation method.

Comment: your code will replace values `0`, `false`, etc with the string "null" - did you want a string?

Comment: @Bravo `[,,]` is [a valid array literal](https://jsbin.com/kenohis/edit?js,console). To the best of my knowledge, no console will output empty slots as "nothing", so printing an array that contains empty slots shouldn't produce something like `[,,]`. Chrome will say "empty x N", Firefox says "<N empty slots>", NodeJS says "<N empty items>" (N is the number of grouped empty slots. So, I doubt OP is *seeing* `[,,]` in some output.

Comment: @VLAZ - I was looking at it from the other way around :p I know that `[,,]` is length 2 not 3 :p ... i.e. I was looking at it like, to get `[,,]` you `Array(3).join()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you can create a new array from [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) then add `null` if there is an `empty slot`

**NOTE**: You have to explicitly check for the existence of index as

```
(!(i in arr)) // if index is present in whole prototype chain
```

**Because there can be a case where you have defined a value as `undefined` then that value you have to skip to override it to null.**

let say you have an array as `[, undefined, ,]` then you want to exclude the `undefined` value at index `1`

```js
function fillEmptySlotsWithNull(arr) {
  return Array.from(arr, (_, i) => {
    if (!(i in arr)) return null;
    else return arr[i];
  });
}

const inputs = [
  [, , , ],
  [, undefined, , ],
  ["value", , ],
  [, "value"],
  [, , "value"],
];

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  const result = fillEmptySlotsWithNull(input);
  console.log(result);
});
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

You can also use old `for-loop` also as:

```js
function fillEmptySlotsWithNullWithForLoop(arr) {
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (!(i in arr)) result.push(null);
        else result.push(arr[i])
    }
    return result;
}

const inputs = [
  [, , , ],
  [, undefined, , ],
  ["value", , ],
  [, "value"],
  [, , "value"],
];

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  const result = fillEmptySlotsWithNullWithForLoop(input);
  console.log(result);
});
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: `Array.from({ length: arr.length }, ...)` Why? o.O -> `Array.from(arr, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You could Proxy the array.  This doesn't modify the original and thus:

- potentially avoids a scan of the original entries (that do not need to be converted)
- you can access the original
- you can add other <s>weird</s> exotic properties to it if needed

```js
const noMoreTrouble = new Proxy(troublesome, {
    get(t,p){
      if( typeof p === 'string' && /^\d/.test(p) && !Reflect.has(t,p)) return null;
      return Reflect.get(t,p); 
    }
});
```

```js
const troublesome= Array(15);

//fill it up for 5.    1/3 empty; 1/3 undefined; 1/3 integers
[...Array(5)].forEach((x,i)=>{   
   troublesome[i+5]=x;
   troublesome[i+10]=i
}   );


const noMoreTrouble = new Proxy(troublesome, {
    get(t,p){
      if( typeof p === 'string' && /^\d/.test(p) && !Reflect.has(t,p)) return null;
      return Reflect.get(t,p); 
    }
});

//true
noMoreTrouble[0] === null;

//false 
troublesome[0] === null;
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/mwzdut3v/)